# How to setState with On/Off buttons in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie and learning ReactJS and doing a little project.

I have two buttons On/Off and when I click on "the light is on" should render on the screen, when I click off "the light is off" should render on the screen.

Right now when I click off it renders off, but when I click it again it renders on, which is not correct. When it's off, when I click the on button, on does not render, which is also not correct.

I think what's happening is when I click the off button, it changes the state to false then back to true because I'm using a '!' operator in setState.

I'm sure this is a simple issue to fix, but having trouble with it.

Any ideas?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import "./index.css";

class Room extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLit: true,
      isOn: true
    };
  }

  flipLight = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLit: !this.state.isLit
    });
  };

  turnOn = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOn: this.state.isOn
    });
  };

  turnOff = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOn: !this.state.isOn
    });
  };

  render() {
    const bright = this.state.isLit ? "lit" : "dark";
    console.log(this.state.isOn);

    return (
      <div className={`room ${bright}`}>
        the room is {this.state.isLit ? "lit" : "dark"} <br />
        the light is {this.state.isOn ? "on" : "off"} <br />
        <button onClick={this.flipLight}>Change State</button>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.turnOn}>On</button>
        <button onClick={this.turnOff}>Off</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Room />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a negation `!this.state.isOn` you are basically toggling the value. So with every click it's a *negation* of the previous value, that's why one time it's `on` and another time `off`.

When turning off, you should just assign a `false` value. When turning on - `true`.

```js
class Room extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLit: true,
      isOn: true
    };
  }

  flipLight = () => {
    this.setState({
      isLit: !this.state.isLit
    });
  };

  turnOn = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOn: true,
    });
  };

  turnOff = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOn: false,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const bright = this.state.isLit ? "lit" : "dark";

    return (
      <div className={`room ${bright}`}>
        the room is {this.state.isLit ? "lit" : "dark"} <br />
        the light is {this.state.isOn ? "on" : "off"} <br />
        <button onClick={this.flipLight}>Change State</button>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.turnOn}>On</button>
        <button onClick={this.turnOff}>Off</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Room />, rootElement);
```

```html
<div id='root'/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For your `flipLight` function, you should use the `setState` function pattern instead of object pattern because it depends on the previous state. Something like  `this.setState(prevState => ({ isLit: !prevState.isLit }))`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
turnOn = () => {
 this.setState({
   isOn: true
 });
};

turnOff = () => {
  this.setState({
    isOn: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `turnOn` method is just resetting the same state. You should change it so that it always sets the state as `true`. As for the `turnOff` method, it should always set the state to `false`:

```
turnOn = () => {
  this.setState({ isOn: true })
}

turnOff = () => {
  this.setState({ isOn: false })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling on and off with different functions the you can set true and false value only update the state like below:

```
  turnOn = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOn: true
    });
  };

  turnOff = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOn: false
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to handle state correctly in your React application. Luckily, arrow functions come in handy here (and seem to be the conventional method of writing onClick functions)

```
turnOn = () => {
  this.setState({
    isOn: true
  });
};

turnOff = () => {
  this.setState({
    isOn: false
  });
};
```